# Angular UI routing loose url parameters after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router, page-refresh

How can keep url parameters for state, after page refresh?

I have this state

```
   .state('App.State', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/App/:param',
        templateUrl: '/page.html',
        controller: 'pageCtrl',
        params: {
            'param': null,
        },

    })
```

I go to this state with this command

```
<a ui-sref="App.State({param: paramName})">{{paramName}}</a>
```

I go to the state, with the params that i want, but when i refresh page (f5) i loose the params, how can keep them after page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TX2tFiG6eofUbXdj2UkQ?p=preview) which does remove `abstract: true` from your code:

```
.state('App', {
      template: '<div ui-view ></div>',
})
.state('App.State', {
      //abstract: true,
      url: '/App/:param',
      templateUrl: 'page.html',
      controller: 'pageCtrl',
      params: {
        'param': null,
      },
    })
```

And then we can use any kind of url (even F5 later) to get to that state

- http://run.plnkr.co/WFREZ72rUUbD4ekc/#/App/SomeParam
- http://run.plnkr.co/WFREZ72rUUbD4ekc/#/App/OtherParam

In case, we want to keep that state abstract - we cannot navigate to it. We need its child. There is [other plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ehY6NnXMaRQTUxbnXyb?p=preview)

```
.state('App', {
      template: '<div ui-view ></div>',
})
.state('App.State', {
      //abstract: true,
      url: '/App/:param',
      templateUrl: 'page.html',
      controller: 'pageCtrl',
      params: {
        'param': null,
      },
})
.state('App.State.Child', {
      url: "/",
      template: '<h4> App.State.Child </h4>',
})
```

The ui-sref cannot be

```
<a ui-sref="App.State({param: 'xxx'})">
  -- not working while abstract
```

we have to go to child

```
<a ui-sref="App.State.Child({param: 'yyy'})">
```

And these will work then

- http://run.plnkr.co/217SWcbOjuv1k3YF/#/App/MyParam/
- http://run.plnkr.co/217SWcbOjuv1k3YF/#/App/MyOtherParam/

Comment: Will the second approach(keep abstract state) work for multiple params, i.e. params object has two keys but only one is displayed in the route? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757390/reload-not-working-when-passing-multiple-params-in-ui-router-state)

Comment: The point is.. **url** is the only part - which will survive the refresh *(or sending the url and opening it later)* The answer is NO. Only `url` stuff will survive. Hope it helps a bit ;) enjoy UI-Router

Comment: please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757390/reload-not-working-when-passing-multiple-params-in-ui-router-state). Can you please suggest a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the values you should add the parameters in the url like this:

```
url: '/App/:param'
```

And remove the params property.