# Reload not working when passing multiple params in ui-router state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am using ui-router with parent and child states. My states are defined as below :

```
.state("home.ben", {
    url: "/beneficiary/:name",
    abstract:true,
    templateUrl: "app/ben/views/ben-form.html",
    controller: "BeneficiaryFormController",
    controllerAs: "bfCtrl",
    params : {id:'',name:''},...

.state("home.ben.general", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "app/ben/views/partials/general.html",
    controller: "BeneficiaryGeneralController",
    controllerAs: "bGenCtrl",
    params:{id:'',name:''},
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label:"General",
        skip: true
    },
    resolve: {...
```

I am routing to the state using `ui-sref = "home.ben.general({id:someID,name:someName})"` or `$state.go("home.ben.general",{id:someId,name:someName})`.

Everything is working fine except that when I refresh the page the view does not load. I think the `id` param is not getting passed when the view reloads.

Any suggestions on how to get this working so that it works even when someone hits 'F5' or refreshes the page?

Comment: Solution here *(in general)* is to - move any param, which should survive page refresh (F5) or work if URL is passed (e.g. via notification) ... **it must be part of the URL**. In this case we should adjust the parent `url: "/beneficiary/:name/:id"` or `url: "/beneficiary/:name?id"`. UI-Router then will generate URL (when $state.go or ui-sref is used) which will keep that info, and will work after page reload... hope it helps a bit